# Two input value in one EditText

Tags: android

In my edit text I have this "1 + 2", how can I put the numbers in different variable for me to be able to compute their sum.

For example I want the first part of the string which is 1 to be stored in variable input1 and the second input which is 2 to be stored in variable input2.

Here is my java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtResult;
    double input1,input2,total;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtResult);
    }

    public void onClickNumber (View v) {
        Button buttons = (Button) v;
        edtResult.setText(edtResult.getText() + buttons.getText().toString()); //

    }

}
```

Comment: Is addition of two numbers the _only_ type of input which you would consider valid, or could there be other, possibly more complex, expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try:

```
String[] inputes = String.valueOf(edtResult.getText()).split("+");
```

it could split the String by plus sign and will return an array of strings which first element (inputes[0]) is the first number in string format.